# Call Retrofit2 + Decrypt + Json conversor

Tags: android, json, encryption, kotlin, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 in kotlin, and I need to get the content that is a json and this encrypted, I know that to convert json just use the `JacksonConverterFactory` (until this part was working well) but an encryption was added before that and I do not know how To handle this, do I need to create a converter of my own? Does anyone have a read to tell me?

My current call for retrofit

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()                
            .baseUrl("http://100.1.1.100/")
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build()
```

And i already have my fucntion (working) to decrypt:

```
CryptAES.decrypt(value))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by creating an decrypt [interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors):

```
class DecryptInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain
            .run { proceed(request()) }
            .let { response ->
                return@let if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val body = response.body()!!

                    val contentType = body.contentType()
                    val charset = contentType?.charset() ?: Charset.defaultCharset()
                    val buffer = body.source().apply { request(Long.MAX_VALUE) }.buffer()
                    val bodyContent = buffer.clone().readString(charset)

                    response.newBuilder()
                            .body(ResponseBody.create(contentType, bodyContent.let(::decryptBody)))
                            .build()
                } else response
            }

    private fun decryptBody(content: String): String {
        //decryption
        return content
    }
}
```

setup:

```
val httpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
httpClient.addInterceptor(DecryptInterceptor())
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://100.1.1.100/")
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(httpClient.build())
        .build()
```